# Unorded lists, how do I get two words broken up from one line onto two lines?

Tags: html, css

I have this site I am working on, it has the following menu items:

> Residents Business Teachers Construction Property Management
>   Municipalities

Is there a way to get Property Management broken up onto two lines within the same list element(figure 1). [image: Figure 1]

Currently the behavior is:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the css3 max-width property on the containing element. You could also just add a `<br/>` for older browsers.

You might also have to set `display` to `inline-block`.